# Transparent form won't always stay on top

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I need Form2 to be always on top of every single window - including games in fullscreen. This always works with windowed-mode applications, but it sometimes won't appear topmost when another app is in fullscreen mode. (Games, OpenGL, direct)

How can I fix this?

Form1:

```
Overlay overlayui = new Overlay();
overlayui.TopMost = true;  // I have tried setting TopMost to false, same result.
overlayui.Show();
```

Form2:

Settings in WinForms designed view:

```
FormBorderStyle = none
ControlBox = false
ShowIcon = false
ShowInTaskBar = false
TopMost = false
```

I've implemented this piece of code used in similar issues:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
public Overlay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }
```

I then implemented a timer (interval 10 ms):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
internal class MessagesFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        private readonly IntPtr ControlHandler;
        private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        public MessagesFilter(IntPtr ControlHandler)
    {
        this.ControlHandler = ControlHandler;
    }
    #region IMessageFilter Members

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        // TODO:  Add MessagesFilter.PreFilterMessage implementation
        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYUP)
        {
            if (m.HWnd == ControlHandler)
            {
                Keys k = ((Keys)((int)m.WParam));
                if (k == Keys.Enter)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

EDIT:

I've implemented new timer :

```
SetWindowPos(processNOtopmost, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE )
```

So first time brings to top my app, and second one is removing from topmost external app. 
Still same problem, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: @chridam Ok, thanks. Sorry for that.

Comment: This is entirely by design.  Lots of DirectX games ask for exclusive access to the video adapter.  And get it, defeating any attempt to overlay another window on them.  Not just to avoid having to deal with windows stealing the foreground and make the player lose control over the game and lose a life, also to defeat various cheat attacks.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: I don't want this to work with directx, it was just an example. I want it to work with OpenGL and it does, but thing is it does only sometimes. Skype notification, mail notification also show On Top of this application.

Comment: Whoever asked last to be top most will win. You cannot always expect your application to be the one that has top priority when other applications might also ask for that right.

Comment: How can override this? Is it possible to make this single process NOT always on top? My app ask last. Still it sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: Raymond Chen covered this a while ago: [How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).  In short: "Stop the madness. The only sane way out is to have the programs coöperate to determine who is in control of the screen at any particular time."  See also: [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx).

Comment: The thing is, it's caused by OpenGL fullscreen. It works, partial, sometimes. As You may noticed I even used 
SetWindowPos(processNOtopmost, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE )
on this OpenGL with no result. It must be some way out of this.

Comment: Again, as @HansPassant said, this is "by design", not a bug. Your program would also probably need to be DirectX, and even then, if there were two DirectX applications running (your program and another game), I'm not entirely sure what would happen. You should look into that link by Raymond Chen and the other link Nick posted in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set:

```
TopMost = true
```

As far as i'm aware though this only makes it the topmost Window for you Application.
You have no control over other applications unless you prevent loss of Focus completely (not advised)
And besides most of the applications that are 'Stealing' focus from you will be DirectX and get priority on the GPU.